# How to override the body css with child css property?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Initially I have body with css as overflow scroll.How can i change the body css to overflow hidden when particular span occurs.Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the screenshot

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

Then apply the above code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('#spanemelementid').length) {
     $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use JQuery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('#spanemelementid').length) {
     $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
}
});
```

Comment: where should I include this

Comment: You can add scripteditor webpart and put this code in that page. Make sure Jquery is loaded in the page

Comment: jQuery isn't necessary to do this.